Java Connection Pool implementation
I am looking into Windows Shares and the smbj library. To speed up multiple requests to the same share I am thinking of connection pooling.
Now all the connection pools I can find out there seem to focus on JDBC, and they are unsuitable for smbj. Whenever I look for a custom build I only get very basic information, like here or here. Preferrably I'd like to use/extend something existing.
Where can I find some generic connection pool implementation?
